# Expected response to be a success, but was 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, missing-template

I have the following articles_controller:

```
def myarticles
    @myarticles = current_student.articles.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml  { render :xml => @myarticles }
    end
end

def create
  @article = current_student.articles.new(params[:article])
    respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'επιτυχώς.') }
      format.xml{render:xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article}
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

on my terminal `rake routes` gives me:

```
myarticles_articles GET /articles/myarticles(.:format)  {:action=>"myarticles", :controller=>"articles"}
```

my config/routes.rb is

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :students

  resources :articles do
    collection do
        get 'about'
        get 'all'
        get 'myarticles'
    end
end

root :to => 'articles#index'
end
```

and my view is in /app/views/articles/myarticles.html.erb

When on my browser I navigate to

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/articles/myarticles
```

I have the error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template articles/myarticles with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/home/panagiotis/projects/sample/app/views", "/home/panagiotis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.5.3/app/views"
```

and when I run rake from the terminal with the following articles_test_controller content:

```
test "should get myarticles signed in" do
    get :myarticles
    assert_response :success
end
```

I get the failure

```
Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <302>
```

I read about redirect to but I can't seem to fix that issue.

Comment: In file myarticles.html.erb properties, permission: I am owner and I have read and write access.

Comment: I am stupid. Here wtite myarticles and on directory write myaricles. Just unbelievable!

Answer (score 1):

To debug your missing template issue, could you try something like:

```
format.html { render 'myarticles' }
```

?

Regarding your specs failure, you likely need to have a current user session in your tests, otherwise it thinks you're a logged out user and redirects you to a login page. I haven't used Devise but it looks like the README has some suggestions under "Test Helpers" : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I make this changes: on articles_controller.rb put after respond_to do |format| --> format.html { render 'myarticles' } and on articles_controller_test.rb put after test "should get myarticles signed in " do -->sign_in students(:student2) (I have on test/fixtures/students.yml student2). Copy paste my template from the path /app/views/articles/myarticles.html.erb to /app/views/myarticles.html.erb but now I have error (from failure) with description ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template articles/myarticles with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs ...