# Why does Rails RSpec response show 302 instead of 401?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-status-code-302, rails-api

I have been stuck on this problem for several days and I don't know what is wrong with it. I started Ruby on Rails few months ago and I am currently learning authentication with API. I have looked at other similar topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315992/expected-response-to-be-a-success-but-was-302) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391818/expected-response-to-be-a-success-but-was-302) but none of them helped.

My problem is whenever I run RSpec on this code (located at `spec/api/v1/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb`)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::PostsController, type: :controller do
  let(:my_user) { create(:user) }
  let(:my_topic) { create(:topic) }
  let(:my_post) { create(:post, topic: my_topic, user: my_user) }

  context "unauthenticated user" do

    it "PUT update returns http unauthenticated" do
      put :update, topic_id: my_topic.id, id: my_post.id, post: {title: my_post.title, body: my_post.body}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
    end
    ...
```

I keep getting

```
...
spec/api/v1/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb -e "unauthenticated user"
Run options: include {:full_description=>/unauthenticated\ user/}
FFF

Failures:

  1) PostsController unauthenticated user PUT update returns http unauthenticated
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
       expected the response to have status code 401 but it was 302
     # ./spec/api/v1/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If this helps, my controller, `app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller_spec.rb` has

```
class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :authenticate_user, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authorize_user, except: [:index, :show]


     def update
       post = Post.find(params[:id])

       if post.update_attributes(post_params)
         render json: post.to_json, status: 200
       else
         render json: {error: "Post update failed", status: 400}, status: 400
       end
     end
    ...
```

My base_controller

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :malformed_request

  def authenticate_user
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      @current_user = User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
  end

  def authorize_user
    unless @current_user && @current_user.admin?
      render json: {error: "Not Authorized", status: 403}, status: 403
    end
  end

  def malformed_request
    render json: {error: "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.", status: 400}, status: 400
  end

  def not_found
    render json: {error: "Record not found", status: 404}, status: 404
  end
end
```

Lastly, routes.rb shows:

```
  namespace :api do
   namespace :v1 do
     resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update]
     resources :topics, except: [:edit, :new] do
       resources :posts, only: [:update, :create, :destroy]
     end
   end
 end
```

I have a strong hunch that my before_action is the culprit, but I can't pinpoint what I did wrong. I have done similar thing on Topics (Posts are nested within Topics) using similar RSpec testing and my Topic RSpec passes, whereas my Posts RSpec fail miserably.

Can someone please help me to point out what I did wrong, and how can I pass the RSpec test and not show 302 status code?

As an extra, *why* did it show 302 status code?

Comment: Perhaps add `puts response.body` and `puts response.current_path` to find out where it's redirecting to?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try `PATCH` instead of `PUT` ? I vaguely recall that PATCH is now rails standard and it might be redirecting a PUT to PATCH ???

Comment: Check if redirect from `ApplicationController`?

Comment: I think the problem is definitely in before_action. You should handle it.You can try debug your tests installing gem 'byebug' and adding code require 'byebyg'; byebug .

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using

`before_action :authenticate_user, except: [:index, :show]`, probably the helper from Devise, correct? If so, when you try to access a resource without being logged in, this helper will **redirect** you to the login page, something that you expect to happen when you're using a browser, which is not your case. You can find some alternatives, overwriting the Devise behavior, my solution was to define my `authenticate_user!` method to return a 401 if the user was not signed in, using another devise helper method, something like this:

```rb
def authenticate_user!
  if user_signed_in?
    @user = current_user
  else
    head :unauthorized
  end 
end
```

This is the case that worked for me, yours may be different.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into to same issue, while normally using

```rb
let(:auth_headers) { Devise::JWT::TestHelpers.auth_headers({ 'ACCEPT': 'application/json' }, user) }

# ...


get "/api/v1/something", headers: auth_headers
```

in my request specs.

I first tried to test the **401 Unauthorized** case by just removing `auth_headers`, which then lead to the unexpected **302 Found** response.

However, testing my API via Postman worked as expected (401 response without auth header).

The solution was to just remove the `Authorization` header and *keeping* the `Accept` header, so the application would know that it's not talking to a user and thus would not redirect to the login page:

```rb
let(:auth_headers) { Devise::JWT::TestHelpers.auth_headers({ 'ACCEPT': 'application/json' }, user) }

# ...


get "/api/v1/something", headers: { 'ACCEPT': 'application/json' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that devise returns HTTP 302 Redirect if the request is made from a browser, otherwise it returns 401 Unauthorized.

I believe the solution is to update the requests in your test file to look like this:

```rb
put :update, topic_id: my_topic.id, id: my_post.id, post: {title: my_post.title, body: my_post.body}, as: :json
```

Comment: yes, the only thing was missing is `as: :json`