# RSpec console log returns 302, but test log shows 401

Tags: rspec, devise

I have a simple test written to check that users can't post into a controller with `before_action :authenticate_user!`. The test reads:

```
context 'when the user is not logged in' do
  it 'returns 401' do
    sign_out user

    post wikis_path(params: wiki)

    expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
  end
end
```

The output in the console is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
       expected the response to have status code 401 but it was 302
```

But when I check the test log it does shows 401:

```
Processing by WikisController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"wiki"=>{"content"=>"Some content"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Moreover, I can open the browser, delete the auth cookie and verify that it does indeed respond with 401.

At first, I thought the redirect was Devise behavior because it says that it is in [their comments](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L99), however neither the log or the behavior do this. There is a [similar (old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340720/why-does-rails-rspec-response-show-302-instead-of-401) of a user not using Devise, but getting the same result. I'll admit, I can't grok all of the Devise code, but I was able to lookup and follow `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` in the Rails code all the way to the end to see that it should have (in his case) returned 401.

What is causing the disagreement between the failing test/output in the console and the logged result in `test.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality, the first status code is 302 (Redirect), then the next is 401. I don't have idea why the `test.log` doesn't show 302. Below is the script for redirect case (ref: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher)

```
context 'when the user is not logged in' do
  it 'returns 401' do
    sign_out user

    post wikis_path(params: wiki)

    expect(response).to have_http_status(302)

    follow_redirect!
    expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't think to follow the redirect! This does work, but with one edit, the final status code is 200 after the successful GET.